# How to find how long my computer is being idle (idle time) on C# desktop

Tags: c#

How to find how long my computer is being idle (idle time) on C# Desktop Application

Idle time is the total time a computer or device has been powered on, but has not been used. If a computer or computer device is idle for a set period of time, it may go into a standby mode or power off.

is there any way to get that ?

Comment: what is IDLE? please define

Comment: Idle time is the total time a computer or device has been powered on, but has not been used. If a computer or computer device is idle for a set period of time, it may go into a standby mode or power off.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13384/Getting-the-user-idle-time-with-C

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If with *idle* you mean time elapsed from last user input (as `GetIdleTime()` function would do) then you have to use `GetlastInputInfo()` function (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

In C# you have to P/Invoke it:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct LASTINPUTINFO {
    public uint cbSize;
    public int dwTime;
}
```

It'll return **number of milliseconds elapsed from system boot of last user input**. First thing you need is then system boot time, you have that from `Environment.TickCount` (number of milliseconds from boot) then:

```
DateTime bootTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);
```

Now you can have time of last input:

```
LASTINPUTINFO lii = new LASTINPUTINFO();
lii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));
GetLastInputInfo(ref lii);

DateTime lastInputTime = bootTime.AddMilliseconds(lii.dwTime);
```

Elapsed time will then simply be:

```
TimeSpan idleTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(lastInputTime);
```

Comment: While this method is pretty good, it should be noted that it's not 100% accurate.

If you run code polling `lastInputTime` over a span of 30 seconds, you will see that the millisecond-value reported is slowly drifting into the future. Probably not a big issue, but it's worth noting.

Comment: @JosteinKjønigsen accuracy is more or less 50 milliseconds (time slice because of low-res time measurement) then you may round idleTime to previous second (or so) but I'm pretty surprised there is a **drift**! Nice catch!!!

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your UI framework (you did not specify), you need to catch the [`WM_ENTERIDLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message and store the time in which the message is received.

How should you catch this message? [These guys will tell you for to do it in winforms.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7bd3e24f-c21c-4490-910d-b47b6becf70d/handling-messages-in-windows-application-c?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: Application idle state isn't _system_ idle state (even if this term is little bit misused here). At application level  it means it has nothing else to process (not limited to user input). At system level it means that user didn't interact with the system.